# Deploying plugins from the Hub using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I've created my DataFusion instance, network, pipelines, secrets, etc.. through Terraform but still have one fundamental gap - my pipelines use plugins that are present in the Hub but not enabled by default, like Python and KinesisStreamingSource - I've found Terraform code that will allow me upload plugins but it assumes I have the jars, which to me suggests that solution is more targeted at custom plugins.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Is there a magic API/Terraform command to do a one step deploy of one of the stock plugins from Hub into my DF instance? I'm convinced I'm doing this wrong as there seems to be nobody else having this same issue.

Any help at all is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you find any answer? how Did you create the secrets?

Answer (score 0):

I Believe that this module [module hub_artifact](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/data-fusion/google/latest/submodules/hub_artifact) can be used to deploy an artifact (plugin) from the GCS bucket of a data fusion instance hub.
However, you should install your plugins in a GCS bucket.

I used the same link with the submodule namespace to create namespaces and preferences.

You can also find github links created by Google for data fusion plugins: for example for http plugin you have the [github page](https://github.com/data-integrations/http).

I hope this helps!